# Swift (iOS 8 SDK) Convert Unmanaged<ABMultiValueRef> to ABMultiValueRef

Tags: swift, unmanaged, abrecordcopyvalue

I need to convert the return value of this function from the AddressBook framework:

```
ABRecordCopyValue(nil, kABPersonPhoneProperty)
```

to a value of type ABMultiValueRef

This function is currently marked as this:

```
func ABRecordCopyValue(record: ABRecordRef!, property: ABPropertyID) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>!
```

So I can convert it to Unmanaged like so:

```
ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty) as Unmanaged<ABMultiValueRef>
```

But then how can I get it as an ABMultiValueRef so that I can pass it to this function?

```
func ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiValue: ABMultiValueRef!, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) -> CFIndex
```

I did this:

```
let managedPhones = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(phones.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef
```

And I keep getting this compiler error:

```
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
%89 = bitcast %objc_object* %88 to %PSs9AnyObject_, !dbg !325
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I have the same error. I am stuck with fetching book records sorted :(

Comment: I have heard that this is because Apple has not yet (as of iOS 8 SDK Beta 4) enabled CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED on AddressBook framework.

Comment: Ok, Now I understand :(

Comment: I posted my solution now. You cannot say as ABMultiValueRef. You should say "as NSObject as ABMultiValueRef". I hope this helps

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(
  peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!,
  didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {

    /* Do we know which picker this is? */
    if peoplePicker != personPicker{
      return
    }

    /* Get all the phone numbers this user has */
    let unmanagedPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty)
    let phones: ABMultiValueRef =
    Unmanaged.fromOpaque(unmanagedPhones.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue()
      as NSObject as ABMultiValueRef

    let countOfPhones = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones)

    for index in 0..<countOfPhones{
      let unmanagedPhone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index)
      let phone: String = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(
        unmanagedPhone.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSObject as String

      println(phone)
    }  
}
```

Comment: Rather than the `fromOpaque`/`toOpaque` dance, why not just do `let phones: ABMultiValueRef = unmanagedPhones.takeUnretainedValue()` and `let phone = unmanagedPhone.takeUnretainedValue() as String`?

Comment: This is a Beta 5 fix. Apple has fixed this now so no need to do all the Unmanaged business.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for a final way to deal with ABRecords in Swift 2, here it is:

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord) {

    let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue()
    let lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue()

    var emails:[String] = []
    let emailRecords = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty).takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef
    let emailsCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(emailRecords)
    for index in 0 ..< emailsCount {
        if let email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailRecords, index).takeRetainedValue() as? String {
            emails.append(email)
        }
    }

    print("Contact selected. firstName: \(firstName), lastName: \(lastName), emails: \(emails)")

}
```

Comment: Such a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Same with me, this probably is a compiler problem. if you want to follow my thread too [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson deprecated Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854952/abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-shouldcontinueafterselectingperson-deprecated)