# Swift Compile Error Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

In Xcode6 beta 1 something similar to this worked, however with Xcode6 beta 4 there were errors. After fixing the errors the errorless code I have is below

**For Background**:
The class I'm using here implements `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate` which allows you the user to select a contact from the address book. I want to get the first email that is added to that person.

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!,didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {

    var emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty)
    var emailsObj = emails.takeUnretainedValue() as AnyObject
    var index = 0 as CFIndex
    var emailAddress = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailsObj, index)

    println(emailAddress)
}
```

However when I compile I get Build Failed:

**Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %80 = bitcast %objc_object* %79 to %PSs9AnyObject_, !dbg !860
Stored value type does not match pointer operand type!
  store %PSs9AnyObject_ %80, %objc_object** %81, align 4, !dbg !860
 %objc_object*Stored value type does not match pointer operand type!
  store %PSs9AnyObject_ %80, %objc_object** %85, align 4, !dbg !864
 %objc_object*LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1**

The suspect lines are:

```
var emailsObj = emails.takeUnretainedValue() as AnyObject
var emailAddress = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailsObj, index)
```

When I change the code to

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!,didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {

    var emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty)
    var emailsObj:AnyObject? = emails.takeRetainedValue() as AnyObject
    var index = 0 as CFIndex
    var emailAddress = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailsObj, index)

    println(emailAddress)
}
```

The error shortens to

**Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %79 = bitcast %objc_object* %78 to %PSs9AnyObject_, !dbg !856
Stored value type does not match pointer operand type!
  store %PSs9AnyObject_ %79, %objc_object** %80, align 8, !dbg !856
 %objc_object*LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1**

Thanks in advance for any help

Aaron

Comment: I saw your comment on the other question, but unfortunately I can't help you much here. I still haven't dedicated time to learn Swift. But, a long shot guess here: does it still fails if you replace the `takeUnetainedValue()` by `takeRetainedValue()`? Also, my playground indicated me to change the `emailsObj` line to `var emailsObj: AnyObject = emails.takeRetainedValue() as AnyObject`, that might be related to your issue somehow.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work, however just for reference do you have any insight to what the difference between takeUnretained() and takeRetainedValue() actually is? I don't quite understand the documentation

Comment: @Aaron If a function's name uses Create or Copy, it is retained, and needs releasing, so if Swift is in doubt you tell it to take the value as retained. Otherwise it is unretained. But if Swift is NOT in doubt you should do nothing.

Comment: @matt  Thanks, when I change it to `var emailsObj:AnyObject? = emails.takeRetainedValue() as AnyObject` it seems to reduce the length of the outputted error(by two lines) but only when I add the `?`  the rest of the error persists even when `var emailAddress = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailsObj, index)` is commented out however.

Comment: Here's a solution - but it's really strange: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24971793/341994 Clearly this module is not well bridged to Swift. You should stick to Objective-C and/or file a bug report.

Comment: @matt It worked, thanks so much. If you wanna write up an answer showing it I can accept it, if not in an hour or so I'll just write up my own so more people can find this solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift (iOS 8 SDK) Convert Unmanaged<ABMultiValueRef> to ABMultiValueRef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678374/swift-ios-8-sdk-convert-unmanagedabmultivalueref-to-abmultivalueref)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!,didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {

    var unmanagedEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty)
    let emailObj: ABMultiValueRef = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(unmanagedEmails.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSObject as ABMultiValueRef

    var index = 0 as CFIndex

    var unmanagedEmail = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailObj, index)
    var emailAddress:String = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(unmanagedEmail.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSObject as String

    println(emailAddress)

}
```

More full answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678374/swift-ios-8-sdk-convert-unmanagedabmultivalueref-to-abmultivalueref).